# Bootstrap Grid Layout Automatic Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to publish my portfolio in my website. And my portfolio images sometimes horizontally wide and sometimes vertically wide. I did research a lil bit and i found this http://www.bootply.com/mohwImsUG4 solution it works great when i upload my vertical images. My question is how can i automatically fix width of grid layout to my images and of course if i have to see 2 images in one line its ok.

Screenshot (My Code)
[image]

Screenshot (Google [What i want])
[image]

Comment: Don't use Bootstrap for this but take a look at jQuery Masonry, see http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: but if i have to use bootstrap. how can i do that?

Comment: That is a masonry layout. There's many scripts to do that. Bootstrap does not do that without adding the scripts and css etc.,

Comment: Well, you could painstakingly work out the necessary static grid layout for your particular images, but I really wouldn't recommend that.